# How to randomly assign a color on hover effect

Tags: html, css

I've never seen a hover effect like this before, and I'm trying to understand how it's achieved. You'll notice [in this example,](http://blog.kylemeyer.com/) that when a user hovers over a link, the color the link turns can be **any one 1 of 5 colors** that are assigned within the style sheet (see below) at random. 
How do you create this hover effect? Can it be done purely with CSS?

```
a:hover {
  color:#1ace84;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  border: 0;
  background-image: none;
  }

a.green:hover { color: #1ace84; }
a.purple:hover { color: #a262c0; }
a.teal:hover { color: #4ac0aa; }
a.violet:hover { color: #8c78ba; }
a.pink:hover { color: #d529cd; }
```

Answer (score 9):

Since a random factor is introduced, I don't think there's a way of doing it purely with CSS.

Here's my simple approach to the problem, using jQuery.

You can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/GNgjZ/1/

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("a").hover(function(e)
    {
        var randomClass = getRandomClass();
        $(e.target).attr("class", randomClass);
    });
});

function getRandomClass()
{
    //Store available css classes
    var classes = new Array("green", "purple", "teal", "violet", "pink");

    //Get a random number from 0 to 4
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);

    return classes[randomNumber];
}
```

Comment: I need to change the hover bg of a div with the class "article-container". Changing "a" to "article-container" does not seem to work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Arete, since you're working with a class you need to use the `.article-container` selector (notice the dot). Also note that this example completely changes the `class` attribute, in your case using `addClass()` and `removeClass()` might be better.

Answer (score 4):

The key piece of jQuery code is loaded in the footer of the page.

Please pay attention to the authors comment on the script, or seek the [author's permission](http://blog.kylemeyer.com/) to reuse it.

```
/* 

  Code below this point is not licensed for reuse,
  please look and learn but don't steal

*/
var lastUsed;
function randomFrom(arr){
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  lastUsed = arr[randomIndex];
  return lastUsed;
}
color_classes = ['green','purple','violet','teal','pink'];
function initLinks() {
  $('#wrap a').hover(function() {
    new_classes = color_classes.slice();

    var index = $.inArray(lastUsed, new_classes);
    new_classes.splice(index, 1);

    var classes = $(this).attr('class');
    if (classes) {
        classes.split(' ');
        $(classes).each(function(i, className) {
            var index = $.inArray(className, new_classes);
            if (index>0) {
                new_classes.splice(index, 1);
            }

        });
    }
    $(this).removeClass(color_classes.join(' ')).addClass(randomFrom(new_classes));
  }, function () {
  });
}
```

Comment: Considering the coders comments I don't think you should have posted their code. Even though the CSS and jQuery is client side and available to everyone it's still their code and they spent time writing it for this guys site. He was honest in commenting code where he made changes and comments his own code. I posted examples below which do the same and haven't been stolen.

Comment: @Anagio The code is on the open web and the author invites you to learn but not steal. So I don't really think there is an issue in posting it. It's also not that unique as your own answer points out.

Comment: my point was the coder took the time to comment code he changed that wasn't his and asked no one steals his custom code. Yes it's on the open web but so are photos which photographers have copyrights to, just because we can download them doesn't mean we should take'em. There are open source apps which you need licenses for and if your found using them without a license you can still file DMCA's against sites even though the code is 100% open source. If the question were asked on StackOverflow i'm sure a few people would have replied with example code in jsfiddle

Comment: Personally I don't think its a problem to have quoted the code. It is being used for learning and I would be reasonably sure that stealing means people using it on their own site, not learning from it in a public forum. If you are particularly concerned you could e-mail the guy and check his intentions. When the question is about a specific page though it is very hard to answer without reference to that specific page.