# Javascript to randomize padding-bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, random

Newbie here to javascript. I tried to follow the link here :
[How to randomly assign a color on hover effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606148/how-to-randomly-assign-a-color-on-hover-effect)

but I failed to replicate the same effect on my #menu_4645908 nav link...

I use #menu_4645908.red:hover  but to no effect.

Note: I did change the variables of the classes from colour to padding , i just used the same class name while i work, will change when its working..

any idea where i went wrong?

**[UPDATE]**

This is the css im using, copied from the thread,

```
#menu_4645908.green:hover { color: #1ace84; }
#menu_4645908.purple:hover { color: #a262c0; }
#menu_4645908.teal:hover { color: #4ac0aa; }
#menu_4645908.violet:hover { color: #8c78ba; }
#menu_4645908.pink:hover { color: #d529cd; }
```

And this is the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("a").hover(function(e) { 
        var randomClass = getRandomClass(); 
        $(e.target).attr("class", randomClass); 
    }); 
}); 

function getRandomClass() { 
   //Store available css classes 
   var classes = new Array("green", "purple", "teal", "violet", "pink"); 

   //Give a random number from 0 to 5 
   var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*6); 

   return classes[randomNumber]; 
}
```

Comment: You are assigning the CSS only to an element with id `menu_4645908`, but you're attaching the `hover()` callback on every single a element. Is this really what you wanted? Are you sure that your `a` element has that ID? Wouldn't `$("#menu_4645908").hover(function(e) {` be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

There seem to have two problems in your code:

1. jQuery has an `addClass()` function that does exactly what you want
2. The class should not be assigned on hover, but rather at the loading of page

So try this instead: ([JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/))

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.each($("a"), function(index, element){
    $(this).addClass(getRandomClass());
  });
});

function getRandomClass() { 
 //Store available css classes 
 var classes = new Array("green", "purple", "teal", "violet", "pink");
 //Give a random number from 0 to 5
 var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*6); 
 return classes[randomNumber]; 
}
```

**EDIT: as user Semicolon said in the comments, this only works if you only wanted the random classes to be assigned at pageload.**

In that case, you could just assign a specific color each time:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  ("a").hover(function(){
    $(this).css('color', getRandomColor());
  }, function(){
    $(this).css('color', ''); // Reverts to default color
  });
}); 

function getRandomColor() {
 var colors = new Array("#1ace84", "#a262c0", "#4ac0aa", "#8c78ba", "#d529cd");
 var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length); 
 return colors[randomNumber];
} ​
```

Comment: This assumes the goal is to make the color random once.  It seems more likely that Da Hao used jQuery's hover specifically to make the color random every time.  If so, it would mean he should unbind the previous hover "event" (really a mouseover event or something) before assigning the new one.  Also, using attr instead of addClass lets you completely overwrite the classes without first removing any previous ones -- which seems consistent with the goal of making it random each time.

Comment: Hi there, im only using this code as im trying it out, but my main purpose is not changing the colour, but the padding of my menu tabs... is there a way to convert it from changing colour to changinf padding?