# Change background color of a div on hover from an array of colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jQuery and I am experimenting a bit here. Please be patient.

I am trying to give div's a "random" background color on hover. If the div is not hovered I want them to be white.

I realize that *random* may not be the right word here because I want the script to chose a color from the following array, preferably in the same order: `['#009c61', '#cc0099', '#cc9900', '#cc0033', '#0099cc', '#6600cc', '#66cc00']`

I guess some of the problem is because all divs have the same class.

How can this be achieved with jQuery?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var bgColorArray = ['#009c61', '#cc0099', '#cc9900', '#cc0033', '#0099cc', '#6600cc', '#66cc00'],
    selectBG = bgColorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgColorArray.length)];

  $('.article-container').css('background-color', selectBG)

});
```

```css
.article-container {
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: solid 3px #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article-container">Div 1</div>
<div class="article-container">Div 2</div>
<div class="article-container">Div 3</div>
<div class="article-container">Div 4</div>
```

So far I have tried this:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var bgColorArray = ['#009c61', '#cc0099', '#cc9900', '#cc0033', '#0099cc', '#6600cc', '#66cc00'],
    selectBG = bgColorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * bgColorArray.length)];

  $('.article-container').css('background-color', selectBG)

});
```

Problem is this changes the color on page refresh and it changes the bg color of all divs.

Comment: where is your jquery code??

Comment: I am not really sure how to implement the `.mouseover` so I have not included it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `.hover(mouseInHandler,mouseOutHandler)` function at this context,

```
var colors = ['#009c61', '#cc0099', '#cc9900', '#cc0033', '#0099cc', '#6600cc', '#66cc00'];
$(".article-container").hover(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", colors[(Math.random() * colors.length) | 0])
}, function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "")
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/feL705ad/1/)

Comment: That came fast. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at this](http://jsfiddle.net/GNgjZ/1/)

Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("a").hover(function(e)
    {
        var randomClass = getRandomClass();
        $(e.target).attr("class", randomClass);
    });
});

function getRandomClass()
{
     //Store available css classes
     var classes = new Array("green", "purple", "teal", "violet", "pink");

     //Give a random number from 0 to 5
     var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*6);

     return classes[randomNumber];
}
```

CSS :

```
a.green:hover { color: #1ace84; }
a.purple:hover { color: #a262c0; }
a.teal:hover { color: #4ac0aa; }
a.violet:hover { color: #8c78ba; }
a.pink:hover { color: #d529cd; }
```

Searched on google and got it from [Telmo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606148/how-to-randomly-assign-a-color-on-hover-effect#answer-9606564)

Answer (score 0):

Cool idea. I just wanted to take a stab at making something pretty.

```js
var numberOfBlocks= 250;
var colors = ['#009c61','#cc0099','#cc9900','#cc0033','#0099cc','#6600cc','#66cc00'];
var lastColor = 0;

(function init() {
  var wrap = document.getElementById('wrap');
  var block = document.createElement('div');
  block.setAttribute('class', 'block');
  for(var i=0; i<numberOfBlocks; i++) {
    wrap.appendChild(block.cloneNode(true));  
  }
  $('.block').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', colors[lastColor++])
    lastColor = (lastColor>=colors.length?0:lastColor);
  },
  function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#fff');
  });
})();
```

```css
.block {
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   border: 1px solid white;
   display: inline-block;
   margin-top: -5px;
   margin-left: -1px;
   transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
</div>
```

Comment: You are thinking bigger! I like it!